# Jquery input mask to input date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I am making a web app which should accept a specific interval that is added to the target date to check if the request is expired. So I need an input with formatting: `months:days:hours`

Where months is limited to 12, days to 31, and hours to 24. I tried to use jQuery [inputmask plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/)

I made like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/qahxvspb/2/

But it doesn't work for some reason, I put a mask like this:

```
mask: "mm-dd-hh"
```

But in the input I get weird stuff, there is still placeholder `mm-dd-yyyy`, and I only can input year into it.

So 2 questions:

1. How to make a correct mask?
2. How can I make allow zero month in the mask? So, basically, it would be optional for the range, if I want I would just put 0 into month, check that on server, and create a range only from days and hours.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Date makes my head hurt because of things like what you are trying to do

I use a library called moment,which is available as a cdn or npm package

It can create input patterns like the one you have, do arithmetic on dates and then convert to the time format you want, even Javascript Date